# New User Feedback

Tags: discussion

I am a new member this year, but I will never return because I am retired and have completed my project.  I strongly feel that I owe SO contributors some positive feedback:  THANK YOU for your help, and for the many research questions that I was able to find answers for in your work.  I used Excel when working, but never VBA, so amazing to me that I was able create a system from info on the web -- where I quickly learned that answers in SO were the best quality source.

I posted 2 questions, the first of which was answered after a little bit of mean, but that's pretty common anytime your getting something for nothing (well worth it to me). The second question did not provide a code solution, but did show me that I needed to give up on that idea, so also very useful.

Comment: The best way to thank the user who best solved your problem is to [accept their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). This indicates to other users that your issue was solved and gives the user who answered you 15 reputation points. (I also want to note how unusual it is for us to get someone saying they're leaving but they're happy with their experience here. Usually when someone says they're leaving the site it's a rant.)